# Rails 3.2.6 & database views creation through migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I'm using rails 3.2.6 and I need to create a database VIEW. As usual I created a migration and I tried to achieve the goal using the execute method.

Unfortunately the migration generates a table, not a view. Why?

Many thanks in advance,
Mauro

UPDATE:

I would like to have something as follows:

```
class CreateMyView < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT ...
    SQL
  end
  def self.down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP VIEW my_view
    SQL
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this migration creates a table...

UPDATE:
the previous code works! I was executing rake db:reset instead of rake db:migrate:reset (my mistake)

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to generate such migration. Use raw SQL to create view.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing (except I'm using def up and def down, not def self.up and def self.down - is there a difference?) and I get the same behavior: it creates a view when I run the migration, but adds a create_table command to the schema.rb file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've answered your own question, but I'll make a related suggestion. Try the [rails_sql_views gem](https://github.com/activewarehouse/rails_sql_views). That link goes to the original repo on GitHub. It looks like it's not being maintained anymore, though. It would be worth looking at the [network graph](https://github.com/activewarehouse/rails_sql_views/network) and trying one of the forks. I'm not *positive* that any of the forks supports Rails 3.2.6, but I'd suggest looking through them. Christian Eichhorn [added support for the mysql2 adapter](https://github.com/webhoernchen/rails_sql_views/commit/e7c2afeea20c369784b59d4e572fbc4ca499c666) about three years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a gem called [rails_db_views](https://github.com/anykeyh/rails_db_views) which is compatible with Rails 4, and still maintained.

Regards,

Yacine.

Comment: Hi Yacine, welcome to StackOverflow. Rather than point to an external example on github, it would be more useful for others looking for a solution if you could specify here what you did to solve the problem.

Comment: Hello Amos! Thanks for your comment. Actually the problem is the migration system as done in Rails is not made to handle views... So there's not "simple" system, and I think you need to implement a new way to manage views. That's why I gave this solution ;)