# Is there a way to de-normalize ActiveRecord associations for a unified view object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a complex object 'Variant' which has many associations. Something on these lines.

```
class Spree::Variant
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :variant_properties
end

class Spree::Product
  has_many :variants
  has_many :properties
end
```

On a page I want to display many variant objects which needs all the product/variant associations and properties. I was using elasticsearch earlier to create a unified view which would encapsulate all this data into one object. On variant save, elasticsearch would update its index with the changed mapped values.

Now I wish to remove elasticsearch and fetch all the data via activerecord. but creating the object with all the data would require a lot of database calls.

Is there a way so I can have the de-normalized object using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

You must use something like `Spree::Product.last.includes(:variants).variants` It explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: no. I'm looking more into a way to create a database view

Comment: you can create views with migration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666736/rails-3-2-6-database-views-creation-through-migrations